# Furnace doesn’t have a c wire and or board

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

Have an old Colman unit in a modular home, needing to hook up c wire adapter. Does not have a circuit board. Any help on trying to hook up c wire would be great. Tried loading photo but will not let me.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have a lowvoltage stat?  Believe it or not, some smaller / older mobile homes controlled the furnace with a line voltage stat! model number of your Coleman unit would help to give you better advice.  EDIT:  Also is it an electric furnace or gas, or oil ?